'Skip navigation doesn't have an inverse navigation configured' error when migrating
I am working on a C# Web API project and when attempting to Add-Migration, I keep getting this error:
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The skip navigation 'Class.Staffs' doesn't have an inverse navigation configured. Every skip navigation should have an inverse skip navigation.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I've got the models:
My Class class
public class Class : IBaseObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Room { get; set; } = null!;
    public int NoPeople { get; set; } // Number of people in the class

    public virtual List<Person> People { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual List<Staff> Staffs { get; set; } = null!;
}

My Person class
public class Person : IBaseObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool Present { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; } = null!;
}

My Staff class
public class Staff : Person
{
    private string Password;

    public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    public bool checkPassword(string attempt)
    {
        string hashed = Crypto.HashPassword(attempt);

        return Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashed, Password);
    }

    public void setPassword(string newPassword)
    {
        Password = Crypto.HashPassword(newPassword);
    }
}

I also have two Join Table classes, ClassList (which joins together Person and Class) and StaffClass (which joins together Staff and Class) which are both in a very similar structure:
public class ClassList
{
    public Person Person { get; set; } = null!;
    public Class Class { get; set; } = null!;

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int ClassID { get; set; }
}

In my DBContext class, I link them together like so:
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Class> Classes => Set<Class>();
    public DbSet<Person> People => Set<Person>();
    public DbSet<ClassList> ClassList => Set<ClassList>();

    public DbSet<Staff> Staffs => Set<Staff>();
    public DbSet<StaffClass> StaffClass => Set<StaffClass>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure the Person-Class many-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassList>()
            .HasKey(cl => new { cl.PersonID, cl.ClassID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Classes)
            .WithMany(p => p.People)
            .UsingEntity<ClassList>(
                r => r.HasOne(x => x.Class)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassID),
                l => l.HasOne(x => x.Person)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonID)
            );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>()
            .HasMany(p => p.People)
            .WithMany(p => p.Classes)
            .UsingEntity<ClassList>(
                r => r.HasOne(x => x.Person)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonID),
                l => l.HasOne(x => x.Class)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassID)
            );

        // Configure the Staff-Class many-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<StaffClass>()
            .HasKey(cl => new { cl.StaffID, cl.ClassID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Classes)
            .WithMany(c => c.Staffs)
            .UsingEntity<StaffClass>(
                r => r.HasOne(x => x.Class)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassID),
                l => l.HasOne(x => x.Staff)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.StaffID)
            );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Staffs)
            .WithMany(c => c.Classes)
            .UsingEntity<StaffClass>(
                r => r.HasOne(x => x.Staff)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.StaffID),
                l => l.HasOne(x => x.Class)
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassID)
            );

        // Other unrelated code here
        }
    }
}


Note that Person and Class should be linked together as they should have a many-to-many relationship, and Staff and Class also should have a many-to-many relationship.
I've tried just doing:
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Classes)
    .WithMany(p => p.People)
    .UsingEntity<ClassList>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Classes)
    .WithMany(c => c.Staffs)
    .UsingEntity<StaffClass>();

But I still get the error. Is there anything I'm missing? What else can I do and why am I getting this error?
